# Jquery get selected text and value from selectlist optgroup

Tags: jquery

I need to get the selected text and value from the optGroup selectList below on the click of a button.  So something like?

```
      $("#addButton").click(function () {

     var selected = ???
});          


  <select name="list">
    <optgroup label="mammals">
      <option>dog</option>
      <option>cat</option>
      <option>rabbit</option>
      <option>horse</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="reptiles">
      <option>iguana</option>
      <option>snake</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Attribute Equals` selector and `val` method.

```
$("#addButton").click(function() {
    // var selected = $('select[name="list"] :selected');
    var val = $('select[name="list"]').val();
});
```

`val` method return the value of selected `option`. However as your option tags have no value attributes, `val` returns the `text` of the selected option.

```
var value = $('select[name="list"] :selected').val();
var text  = $('select[name="list"] :selected').text();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DRDsS/

Comment: Great thanks for your reply.  I forgot to put values in my original code snippet so say I have

 <option value='14'>Fish</option> 

How would I get the value and text for the selected option

Answer (score 0):

Provide an id to your select like "list", and you can try this

```
$(function(){
   $("#addButton").click(function () {
       var select = $('select#list');
       var selectedItem= select.find(':selected');
       var selectedVal = select.val();
       var selectedText = selectedItem.text();
       var optgroupLabel = selectedItem.parent().prop('label');
       alert("val =" + selectedVal + " text ="+ selectedText+" group =" + optgroupLabel );
   });       
});
```

Check this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MJ26K/3/)**

Hope it will help.

Comment: That is great thank you.   However how would I get the selected text and value (not the option group)   so say if I have values for each option       

<option value='7'>Fish</option>
<option value='14'>Cat</option>

Thanks!

Comment: Check updated answer. It is returning text, value and group label. and demo is also updated.